# Unable to install java in ubuntu 20.10 with the error of Unable to fetch some archives

Tags: java, linux, terminal

I am using ubuntu 20.10 and I am trying to install java by the terminal of course. I get the error message E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing? I tried both of the commands but they don't help in a thing. The full error message:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-lts/openjdk-11-jdk_11.0.11+9-0ubuntu2~20.10_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::19 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/j/java-atk-wrapper/libatk-wrapper-java_0.38.0-1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::19 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/j/java-atk-wrapper/libatk-wrapper-java-jni_0.38.0-1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::19 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/x/xorgproto/x11proto-dev_2020.1-1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::19 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libi/libice/libice-dev_1.0.10-1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::19 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/x/xorgproto/x11proto-core-dev_2020.1-1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::19 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libx11/libx11-dev_1.6.12-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::19 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxt/libxt-dev_1.2.0-1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::19 80]
```

I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/416930/how-do-i-solve-unable-to-fetch-some-archives-maybe-run-apt-get-update-or-try-w) post that I think everyone who had the same issue came to this post, but nothing helped me to get out of the problem, in [this](https://guatewireless.org/como-instalar-java-ubuntu-20-10/) another post (in Spanish) tells many ways to download, but nothing helps. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: These packages don't exist. Would be useful to show us how you try to install Java

Comment: In the second link, I show the steps that I did to install it (or try) I'll put the translation rn

Comment: Try to change mirror site `How can I get apt to use a mirror close to me, or choose a faster mirror?` (https://askubuntu.com/questions/37753/how-can-i-get-apt-to-use-a-mirror-close-to-me-or-choose-a-faster-mirror)

Comment: If there are no special requirements, using `sdkman` (https://sdkman.io/install) to install JDK is the easiest choice.

Comment: I tried to download any other app from the terminal like steam but I get a repository error, and if I open the software updater I can't update the system

Comment: Hello everyone, installing ubuntu 22.04 was the solution for me, as the previous version didn't worked